# Periodic rustling noise every 6.5m

Tags: toyota, noise, 4wd

Driving a 2005 Hilux (KUN26 frame, manual diesel), I recently started hearing a soft rustling periodic noise seemingly coming from the front-left side (could be the wheel/tire). It feels like as if the tire was a bit uneven/damaged or with low air pressure. The period pretty much depends on the speed: I counted the number of noise cycles per known road distance and the period appears to be roughly 6.5m.

However, the tire diameter is 31" which makes the circumference roughly 2.5m long only, so I cannot see how it would produce a noise with 6.5m period. Then, all 4 tires looks good to me.

The noise started after driving several hundred kms since installing new tires, doing wheel alignment and changing all gear oils. Does anybody have an idea where the noise might be coming from?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is that 6.5 *meters* or 6.5 *miles*?

Comment: That's _meters_

Comment: Check your wheel bearings.

Answer (score 1):

As @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 suggested, I asked my mechanic to check the wheel bearings. The noise was found to be coming from the rear left one. We disassembled the bearing itself (as we decided to replace both rear ones), and the inner bit appeared to be this:

[image]

The vehicle was at 180,000 kms, though I am not sure if the deterioration was gradual as I started noticing the noise soon after driving on a bumpy uneven mountain road where the bearings could have suffered extensive pressure.

Not sure why there was the 6.5m period, but anyway, now the noise has gone.