# Rear wheel alignment on rear-wheel-drive vehicle

Tags: toyota, wheels, rear-differential, wheel-bearing, rwd

I recently got rear wheel bearings replaced on my 2005 Toyota Hilux (KUN26 frame) and now wondering if the wheels need alignment in order to prevent excessive tire wear.

On the one hand, the rear wheels on this model do not seem turn in any way; they are sturdily attached and therefore one may think they are not supposed to be aligned at all.

On the other hand, when I previously did all-four wheel alignment for the vehicle, the report showed that camber and toe for the rear wheels was actually changed, even though there was no Specified Range for them:

[image]

I am therefore wondering if the rear wheels

1. were actually aligned. If they were, which bolts/nuts etc. were
   actually adjusted?
2. are supposed to be aligned on 2005 Toyota Hilux (KUN26 frame), in particular when the wheels or wheel bearings are changed?
3. are supposed to be aligned on rear-wheel-drive vehicles at all?

Answer (score 1):

Rear wheels can be put out of alignment by hitting kerbs etc.

Fitting hub bearings, either semi, 3/4, or fully floating types does not affect the alignment, but collapsed bearings will - however other problems are more obvious...

As for adjustment , some of the fixings are designed with eccentric bushes ie the hole is off-centre to allow adjustment, or the bar has an adjustment mechanism built in.

Comment: The bearing wasn't collapsed, it was just worn and noisy ([details here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/48233/periodic-rustling-noise-every-6-5m)). Is that nothing to worry about wheel alignment?

Comment: Fitting hub bearings, either semi, 3/4, or fully floating types does not affect the alignment, unless it had excessive play which should then bring it back to standard.